# Django doesn't render the requested view

Tags: python, django, urlconf

people. I'm a beginner Django developer so sorry if it's a basic question.

I have a webpage that shows a list of movies and each movie has a details view, but for some reason, the details view is never rendered.

```
#views.py

def index(request):
    latest_movies = Movie.objects.order_by('-movie_id')[:5]

    template = loader.get_template('ytsmirror/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_movies' : latest_movies,
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def detail(request, movie_id):

    movie = Movie.objects.get(movie_id=movie_id)
    template = loader.get_template('ytsmirror/details.html')

    context = {
        'movie' : movie,
        'plot': 'Lorem impsum',
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

And my urls.py

```
#urls.py

from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'ytsmirror'
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'$', views.index, name='index'),
  url(r'^(?P<movie_id>\d{4})$', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

When I try to reach /ytsmirror/4200/ for example, I don't get any error and Django apparently reaches the correct URL pattern but doesn't render the details view, it stays on the index view, without any change.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: try to replace url(r'$', views.index, name='index') with:
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')

Comment: It worked. Thanks! Could you explain what was happening?

Comment: @pythad explanation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`url(r'$', views.index, name='index')` matches the end of the string, so basically it will match any url, that's why your code isn't working. You need to replace `url(r'$', views.index, name='index')` with `url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')` so that it will match only empty url

`^` asserts position at start of the string

`$` asserts position at the end of the string, or before the line terminator right at the end of the string (if any)